# SSIS For Loop stops after one successful iteration

Tags: c#, for-loop, ssis

I've been writing an ETL that pulls in data from Excel files into a SQL Server database.  The original (working) program was written in Visual Studio 2019 and is being moved over to a Visual Studio 2017 environment.
For Loop:

[image: 1]

It has the following settings:

[image: 2]

The code looking for the file is:

[image: 4]

The for loop then goes through a Excel Source -> OLE DB Destination setup for one file

Last but not least, it resets the @[User::FileExist] = 0.

The for loop with execute until it find the first file, does its work per the contents of the loop and then exits out without continuing to check.  The loop works in the 2019 edition, but not the 2017 edition.

Any help or ideas of where to look would be appreciated.

Comment: You are aware that from the 2016 release of SSIS, you can go into your project's Properties menu and change the targeting of the package from 2019 to 2017?